# Render kmz file data on google map with geoxml3

Tags: google-maps, kml, kmz, geoxml3

I use kmz branch of geoxml3 to simple render geo date from kmz file. But it works not well. Placemarks are rendering fine, but I cant see any overlays. This is my code:

```
    $doc->addScript($this->baseurl.'/components/com_google_map/assets/ZipFile.complete.js', 'text/javascript');
    $doc->addScript($this->baseurl.'/components/com_google_map/assets/geoxml3.js', 'text/javascript');
    $doc->addScript($this->baseurl.'/components/com_google_map/assets/ProjectedOverlay.js');
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("earth", "1");
        var myMap;
        var minZoomLevel = 3;
        var geoXml;
          function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.01, 82.85),
              zoom: 8,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                mapOptions);
            geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({map: myMap, afterParse: showGeoData});
            geoXml.parse('/components/com_google_map/soil_moisture/soil.zip');
          }
          function showGeoData(doc) {
                console.log(doc);
                geoXml.showDocument(doc);
        };
    </script>
```

And this is kml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
<Document>
  <name>Soil_Moisture</name>
  <description>Retrieved soil moisture value
SM_OPER_MIR_SMUDP2_20120916T130233_20120916T135546_551_001_1</description>
  <GroundOverlay>
    <name>Raster data</name>
    <visibility>1</visibility>
    <LatLonBox>
      <north>90.0</north>
      <south>-90.0</south>
      <east>180.0</east>
      <west>-180.0</west>
      <rotation>0</rotation>
    </LatLonBox>
    <Icon>
      <href>overlay.png</href>
    </Icon>
  </GroundOverlay>
  <ScreenOverlay>
    <name>Legend</name>
    <Icon>
      <href>legend.png</href>
    </Icon>
    <overlayXY x="0" y="1" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
    <screenXY x="0" y="1" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction" />
  </ScreenOverlay>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Both of png files were included at kmz. And there are no errors or warnings in console.
Could anyone help?

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Do you have a public link where I can get a sample of the KMZ file?

Comment: @geocodezip,
yep. iwep.wc.lt/components/com_google_map/soil_moisture/soil.zip This file was generated by esa visat

Comment: @geocodezip there are no ideas, as I understand.

Comment: No, all the lack of updates means is I haven't had time to investigate yet.

Comment: [This example of a KMZ file from Google's documentation works](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/EtnaEruptionGroundOverlay.kmz) haven't discovered why yours doesn't

Comment: [This example of a PNG overlay of US counties (and mt. etna erupting) in a KMZ file works](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/GroundOverlayTest.kmz)

Comment: @geocodezip,
I found the problem. Projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel() method returns wrong values for my bounds. For longitude bounds [-180, 180] width in px every time less than 1 (I think that this is a bug). And for latitude bounds [-90, 90] height is too big. This is a projection problem.

Comment: From kml documentation:
<north> Specifies the latitude of the north edge of the bounding box, in decimal degrees from 0 to ±90.
<south> Specifies the latitude of the south edge of the bounding box, in decimal degrees from 0 to ±90.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the Google Maps Javascript API v3 [fromLatLngToDivPixel method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapCanvasProjection), that is returning pretty much the same x coordinate for -179 and +179. I get `c1 = {x: 375.42221937777776, y: 555.1613876295404};`, `c2= {x: 372.5777777777778, y: 44.83861237045963};` (on my [test page](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/soil_mod.kmz)) , which can't be right.

Comment: [jsfiddle demonstrating the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lfc0tb0/)

Comment: Created an issue in the issue tracker ([gmaps-api-issues](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/)) - [issue 7382](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7382)

Comment: looking at your image, it has a lot of empty space. If you tighten down the bounds and clip the image to fit them (rather than covering the whole globe), it should work.